# How to do a POST instead of GET when calling sql.execute()?

Tags: carto

I am calling the CartoDB sql.execute() function with a rather large WKT geometry in the SQL query and this is causing a "414 Request-URI Too Large" error on the server b/c it is making a GET request.

My question is how to I make the sql.execute() function make a POST instead of a GET so I can perform a large SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use type option in execute:

```
sql.execute(sql, vars, { type: 'POST' }, callback)
```

I filed a ticket to switch to POST when the query is too large:
https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/issues/112

In any case if you could rewrite sql to fit GET lenght it will be much better because cartodb can use caching